# Filter Array in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm new in android.. How do I filter an `ArrayList` in android. I have the following `JSON response` and I want to remove those `null objects`, Please refer on my example:

```
    {
      name: "7-11 上海店",
      name_en: "7-11 Shanghai",
      address: "浦东新区陆家嘴环路1396号",
      address_en: "12344",
      logo: "http://google.com/images/7eleven.gif",
      items: [{
          description: "(null)",
          quantity: 0,
          price: 0
      },
      {
          description: "Item 1",
          quantity: 1,
          price: 19.9
      }
    ],
      amount_due: 19.9
   }
```

In this example I want to remove :

```
{
    description: "(null)",
    quantity: 0,
    price: 0
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want to remove only "description" or whole object?

Comment: The whole object. I already figured out thanks! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer. for those who has the same problem with mine. you can use this solution to remove specific item on your `array`:

```
yourArray.removeAll(Collections.singleton("item_you_want_to_remove"));

e.g in my case:

myArray.removeAll(Collections.singleton("(null)"));
```

This works fine!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to map the json to some Business Logic classes with GSON.
It's a free library from Google.
[Link to GSON](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/&ei=Il0xUoDGHquv7AaCvIHQBg&usg=AFQjCNGGFFMez8-PfFoEQP93a7eHFY8ssA&sig2=W7nNktuiXs-ZSh1hXktItg&bvm=bv.52109249,d.ZGU)